# Bash code for Selecting few columns from a variable

Tags: awk

In a file I have a list of coordinates stored (see figure, to the left).
From there I want to copy the coordinates only (red marked) and put them in another file.

I copy the correct section from the file using `` COORD=`grep -B${i} '&END COORD' ${cpki_file} ``. Then I tried to use `awk` to extract the required numbers from the `COORD` variable . It does output all the numbers in the file but deletes the spaces between values (figure, to the right).

How to write the red marked section as they are?

[image]

```
N=200
NEndCoord=`grep -B${N} '&END COORD' ${cpki_file}|wc -l`
NCoord=`grep -B${N} '&END COORD' ${cpki_file}| grep -B200  '&COORD' |wc -l`
let i=$NEndCoord-$NCoord

COORD=`grep -B${i} '&END COORD' ${cpki_file}`

echo "$COORD" | awk '{ print $2 $3  $4 }'
echo "$COORD" | awk '{ print $2 $3  $4 }'>tmp.txt
```

Comment: You need to print "     " or a \t etc. instead. Putting extra spaces between your $'s will be ignored. edit e.g.  `awk '{ print $2 " " $3 " " $4 }'` or  `awk '{ print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 }'` etc. edit2: or you can use comma's instead `awk '{ print $2, $3, $4 }'` final edit: If you want - you can even do  `awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $2, $3, $4 }' ` if you want to do the same thing each time (in this case insert a tab)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of input and desired output.  Pictures are not easy to cut-n-paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start using combinations of `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `cut` and alike, you should realize you can do it all in a single awk command. In case of the OP, this would do exactly the same:

```
awk '/[&]END COORD/{p=0}
     p { print $2,$3,$4 }
     /[&]COORD/{p=1}' file
```

This parses the file keeping track of a printing flag `p`. The flag is set if "&COORD" is found and unset if "&END COORD" is found. Printing is done, only when the flag `p` is set. Since we don't want to print the line with "&END COORD", we have to reset the flag before we do the check for the printing. The same holds for the line with "&COORD", but there we have to reset it after we do the check for the printing (its a bit a weird reversed logic).

The problem with the above is that it will also process the lines

```
UNIT angstrom
```

If you want to have these removed, you might want to do a check on the total columns:

```
awk '/[&]END COORD/{p=0}
     p && (NF==4){ print $2,$3,$4 }
     /[&]COORD/{p=1}' file
```

Of only print the lines which do not contain "UNIT" or are empty:

```
awk '/[&]END COORD/{p=0}
     p && (NF>0) && ($1 != "UNIT"){ print $2,$3,$4 }
     /[&]COORD/{p=1}' file
```

Comment: You could also do `NF!=4{p=0}`

Comment: @WilliamPursell True, but I don't know if that really resembles what the OP stands for. There could be lines in the "COORD" block after the blank line or UNIT line that are still of interest. This choice is up to the originator of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` one-liner:

```sh
sed -n '/^&COORD$/,/^UNIT/{s/.*[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)/\1\t\2\t\3/p}' <infile.txt >outfile.txt
```

Explanation:

Invocation:

- `sed`: stream editor

  - `-n`: do not print unless eplicit

Commands in `sed`:

- `/^&COORD$/,/^UNIT/`: Selects groups of lines after `&COORDS` and before `UNIT`.
- `{s/.*[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)/\1\t\2\t\3/p}`: Process each selected lines.

  - `s/.*[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)`: Regex capture space delimited groups except the first.
  - `/\1\t\2\t\3/`: Replace with tab delimited values of the captured groups.
  - `p`: Explicit printout.